# How can I format an integer to DD format

Tags: java, date, datetime

I need to convert the integer 1,2...9 in 'DD' format i.e; to O1, 02, ....09

For January the below code returns 0

```
 int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

How can I return the month in MM format?

Comment: Seriously, you just need an `if` test, and concatenate "0" with a number. You should figure that out by yourself.

Comment: If you have date or calendar object then use SimpleDateFormat. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

A number is just a number, it has no format.

When you convert it to text, such as a String, you introduce a format. e.g.

```
int num = 5;
String text = String.format("%02d", num);
```

The number `5` has no format but when converted to text this way it will be `"05"`

BTW Instead of using Calender, I suggest you use the JSR-310 library added to Java 8 and available for older version of Java.  You can do things like

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(today);
```

prints

```
2015-02-02
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `String.format()` method.

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
String monthAsTwoDigit = String.format("%tm", cal);
System.out.println(monthAsTwoDigit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat using Parameter **MM**

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

Output for **Month February**

```
02
```

See  [Google Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for other formats